# Dispatcher servlet spring and url pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring framework I today I ran into dispatcher servlet configuration in web.xml file and i came up with a question concerning url pattern like this syntax /. So what does actually the "/" symbol apply in case I deploy web application in tomcat server as following: host:port/ or host:port/myWeb/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pattern `/` will make your servlet the default servlet for the app, meaning it will pick up every pattern that doesn't have another exact match.

### URL pattern mapping :

> - A string beginning with a / character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the **default** servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is `null`.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

### Rules for path mapping :

> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the `/` character as a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. `.jsp`), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last `.` character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a **default** servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.

Comment: hi, so the pattern is for myWeb application folder or for root folder which is webapps?

Comment: Your web app. When you specify `host:port/` then Tomcat serves you the default app.