# HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I am trying to insert the data into database and view the data into crud format. But it shows the error message HTTP Status 404

i have checked the code line by line, there is no error.

but cant display the data into the crud view.

Employee.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Add / Edit Employee!!!</h3>

    <form method="post" action="/SpringMVCTutorial/employee.html" commandName="employee">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 300px">

                <input type="text" name="id" />


                <input type="text" name="name" />


                <input type="text" name="age" />


                <input type="text" name="dept" />

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>List of Employees</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 300px">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Edit/Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="$ {employeeList}" var="employee">

            <tr>
                <td width="60" align="center">${employee.id}</td>
                <td width="60" align="center">${employee.name}</td>
                <td width="60" align="center">${employee.age}</td>
                <td width="60" align="center">${employee.dept}</td>
                <td width="60" align="center"><a href="edit/${employee.id}">Edit</a>/<a href="delete/${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Employee.java

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1280037900360314186L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String dept;
    public Employee()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age, String dept)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getDept()
    {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(String dept)
    {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((age == null) ? 0 : age.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dept == null) ? 0 : dept.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (age == null)
        {
            if (other.age != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!age.equals(other.age))
            return false;
        if (dept == null)
        {
            if (other.dept != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dept.equals(other.dept))
            return false;
        if (id == null)
        {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null)
        {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", dept=" + dept + "]";
    }
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController
{
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            if(employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(employee.getId()) != null);
            employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
        }
        catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e)
        {
            System.out.println("inside catch");
            employeeDAO.saveEmployee(employee);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employees");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("employees");

        employee = employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(id);
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();

        model.addObject("employee",employee);        
        model.addObject("employeeList",employeeList);

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employees");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees")
    public ModelAndView listEmployees(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("employees");

        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
        System.out.println(employeeList);
        model.addObject("employeeList", employeeList);

        return model;
    }
}
```

EmployeeDao.java

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.util.List;
public interface EmployeeDAO
{
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee);
    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id);
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee);
    public void deleteEmployee(int id);
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();
}
```

EmployeeDaoImpl.java

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO
{

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    // JdbcTemplate setter
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate)
    {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    // Saving a new Employee
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        String sql = "insert into employee1 values(?,?,?,?)";
        System.out.println("dao called");
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]
        { employee.getId(), employee.getAge(), employee.getDept(), employee.getName() });
    }

    // Getting a particular Employee
    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id)
    {
        String sql = "select * from employee1 where id=?";
        Employee employee = (Employee) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]
        { id }, new RowMapper<Employee>()
        {
            @Override
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                employee.setAge(rs.getInt(2));
                employee.setDept(rs.getString(3));
                employee.setName(rs.getString(4));
                return employee;
            }
        });
        return employee;
    }

    // Getting all the Employees
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees()
    {
        String sql = "select * from employee1";

        List<Employee> employeeList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Employee>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Employee> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException
            {
                List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    employee.setAge(rs.getInt(2));
                    employee.setDept(rs.getString(3));
                    employee.setName(rs.getString(4));
                    list.add(employee);
                }
                return list;
            }

        });
        return employeeList;
    }

    // Updating a particular Employee
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        String sql = "update employee1 set age =?, dept=?,name=? where id=?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]
        { employee.getAge(), employee.getDept(), employee.getName(), employee.getId() });
    }

    // Deletion of a particular Employee
    public void deleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        String sql = "delete employee1 where id=?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]
        { id });
    }
}
```

SpringMVC-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javainterviewpoint" />


    <bean id="employeeDAOImpl" class="com.javainterviewpoint.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Configurations -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/headway" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="toor" />
     </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `action` attribute has wrong url:

```
<form method="post" action="/SpringMVCTutorial/employee.html" commandName="employee">
```

As per controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee)
```

Your action url must be some what:

```
<form method="post" action="employee" commandName="employee">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us which url pattern spring dispatcher servlet is mapped to?

I suppose that your spring dispatcher servlet in web.xml file is mapped to something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and since your saveEmployee method based on this line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee",method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

is mapped to "/employee", your form in jsp file should be like this:

```
<form method="post" action="test/employee">
```

A point here which is worth mentioning is that "test/employee" is a relative address and definitely it is possible to use an absolute one.

just give this a try and let me know the result.
hope it helps.

Comment: <display-name>Spring MVC CRUD Example</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
this is my web.xml

Comment: You have to map spring dispatcher servlet to a different pattern, something like the one in my post.
When it is mapped to "/" it becomes the default servlet for you web application. 
To understand the difference between "/" and "/*" take a look at this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360374/dispatcher-servlet-spring-and-url-pattern